# Apple Maps sheet transition when another sheet gets presented on top

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

I am trying to recreate the sheet transition animation like the one in Apple Maps. For example, when you tap on a place, another sheet pops on top of the current sheet and it sorts of 'merges' with the sheet right below it.

Here's a video of what I am exactly referring to: https://streamable.com/guz5cf

Like how do I go about doing it? Searched all over the place with zero information

Is it a view controller or a UIView and are the any masking/blend modes involved? I am trying to understand what sorts of techniques can be used to achieve it. Custom presentation controllers?

Would appreciate if anyone can give a simple example to start from.

This is the code I tried but it is no where close to what is in Apple Maps

```
import UIKit


class ViewControllerStack {
    static let shared = ViewControllerStack()
    
    var views: [UIViewController] = []
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        view = MKMapView()
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let welcomeVC = WelcomeViewController()
        welcomeVC.isModalInPresentation = true
        if let sheet = welcomeVC.sheetPresentationController {
            sheet.detents = [.custom { context in
                return 200
            }, .medium(), .large()]
            sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = true
            sheet.preferredCornerRadius = 15
            sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .large
        }
        
        present(welcomeVC, animated: true)
        ViewControllerStack.shared.views.append(welcomeVC)
    }
}

class WelcomeViewController: UIViewController {
    lazy var blurEffectView: UIVisualEffectView = {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemChromeMaterial)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
        return blurEffectView
    }()
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {            
        view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        view.sendSubviewToBack(blurEffectView)            
                
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Go to View Controller 2", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
        ])
        
        
    }
    
    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        let vc2 = ViewController2()
        vc2.modalPresentationStyle = .currentContext
        vc2.modalTransitionStyle = .coverVertical

        present(vc2, animated: true)
        
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.75) {
            self.view.alpha = 0
            self.view.layer.masksToBounds = true
        }

        ViewControllerStack.shared.views.append(vc2)
    }
}

class ViewController2: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemChromeMaterial)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        view.sendSubviewToBack(blurEffectView)
        
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("Go back to Welcome VC", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(buttonTapped), for: .touchUpInside)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),
            button.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 200),
            button.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 44)
        ])
    }
    
    @objc func buttonTapped() {
        ViewControllerStack.shared.views.removeLast()
        guard let lastVCInStack = ViewControllerStack.shared.views.last else { return }
        
        lastVCInStack.view.alpha = 1
        lastVCInStack.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

Comment: Use the same `sheet` properties for your second VC that you're using for the Welcome VC

Answer (score 1):

There is a bit to unpack here...

You are trying to emulate the "double sheet" behavior of the Apple Maps app. It's pretty straightforward to present a sheet controller, and then present another one on top of it - which is what it appears Maps does.

However, based on your comments (and your multiple other questions), you want the sheet(s) to have translucency.

Couple issues with that.

When views with less-than 100% opacity overlap, the alphas get added together. In this image, I have two views with white background, each set to `.alpha = 0.75`:

[image]

As we see, the overlap area is much more opaque. This is not noticeable in the Maps app, because the sheet views have an alpha of probably `0.99` or `0.995` -- so the single sheet is *just barely* translucent, and when the second sheet is presented on top there is virtually no translucency. One has to look really, really closely to even see it.

The second issue is that a presented sheet controller has a shadow behind it.

Here is how it looks when presenting a controller with a completely clear background:

[image]

and, when presenting a second sheet on top of it, we get a darker shadow (two shadow layers):

[image]

If we drag the second sheet up to a taller detent, it's very obvious what's going on:

[image]

Again, in the Maps app, not noticeable because the sheets have almost-opaque backgrounds... however, if we do a screen-cap and zoom way in, we *can* see the extra shadow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IzzZS.png

So, how to get this appearance / behavior:

[image]

***One approach*** is to present a single controller which will hold two "container" views. We load the "content" controllers as children, and add their views to the "container" views, positioning the "detail" view below the "welcome" view.

To show the "detail" view, we can slide it up, collapsing the height of the "welcome" view. Reverse the process to "dismiss" it.

Here is some quick example code - no `@IBOutlet` or `@IBAction` connections... just create a new project and use a default view controller.

---

**View Controller class**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {

    override func loadView() {
        view = MKMapView()
    }
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        if let v = view as? MKMapView {
            // allow default POI selection
            v.selectableMapFeatures = [.pointsOfInterest]
            v.delegate = self

            // let's start the map near Apple HQ
            let c = CLLocation(latitude: 37.32874666861649, longitude: -122.01263053521025)
            let regionRadius: CLLocationDistance = 500
            let coordinateRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: c.coordinate,
                                                      latitudinalMeters: regionRadius * 2.0,
                                                      longitudinalMeters: regionRadius * 2.0)
            v.setRegion(coordinateRegion, animated: false)
        }
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let containerVC = SheetContainerVC()
        containerVC.isModalInPresentation = true

        if let sheet = containerVC.sheetPresentationController {

            sheet.detents = [.custom { context in
                return 200
            }, .medium(), .large()]
            sheet.prefersGrabberVisible = true
            sheet.preferredCornerRadius = 15
            sheet.largestUndimmedDetentIdentifier = .large

        }
        
        // closure so we can de-select the current POI
        containerVC.detailCloseTapped = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            if let v = view as? MKMapView,
               let f = v.selectedAnnotations.first
            {
                v.deselectAnnotation(f, animated: true)
            }
        }

        present(containerVC, animated: true)

    }
    
    // user selected a POI
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect annotation: MKAnnotation) {
        if let feat = annotation as? MKMapFeatureAnnotation {
            if let vc = presentedViewController as? SheetContainerVC {
                vc.showDetail(feat)
            }
        }
    }
    
    // user tapped the map NOT on a POI, or
    //  user tapped a Second POI, which de-selects the First POI
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect annotation: MKAnnotation) {
        // curiously, didDeselect is called twice
        //  the second time, annotation is nil, even though Xcode
        //  says it is not optional
        guard annotation != nil else { return }
        // when a MKAnnotation (POI) is already selected, and the user
        //  selects another POI, didDeselect is called
        //  and then didSelect is called
        // we want to delay "dismissing" the detail view
        //  if we are "replacing" the selected POI
        DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
            self?.delayedDeselect(annotation: annotation)
        }
    }
    func delayedDeselect(annotation: MKAnnotation) {
        if let v = view as? MKMapView, v.selectedAnnotations.count == 0 {
            // user tapped the map NOT on a POI, so
            //  "dismiss" the details view
            if let vc = presentedViewController as? SheetContainerVC {
                vc.hideDetail()
            }
        }
    }

    // use default "ballon" annotation view
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        return MKMarkerAnnotationView()
    }
    
}
```

---

**Container Controller class** - *this will be sheet-presented*

```
// this VC will be presented in sheet mode
//  it will manage the views from Welcome and Detail controllers
class SheetContainerVC: UIViewController {
    
    // closure to tell the map view we closed the detail VC
    var detailCloseTapped: (()->())?
    
    // "container" views for the views from the child controllers
    let welcomeView = UIView()
    let detailView = UIView()
    
    // the two controllers we will add as children
    let wvc = WelcomeVC()
    let dvc = DetailVC()
    
    // top anchor for detail view
    var detailTop: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .clear
        
        let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: .systemThinMaterial)
        let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: blurEffect)
        blurEffectView.frame = view.bounds
        view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
        
        // if we want the blurEffectView to be more Translucent
        blurEffectView.alpha = 0.75
        
        [welcomeView, detailView].forEach { v in
            v.clipsToBounds = true
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        
        // welcome view height
        //  it will be "collapsed" when detail view is shown
        var welcomeHeight: NSLayoutConstraint = welcomeView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor)
        welcomeHeight.priority = .required - 1
        
        // top anchor for detail view
        //  its .isActive will be toggled to animate it into view
        detailTop = detailView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor)
        
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            welcomeView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor),
            welcomeView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            welcomeView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            welcomeHeight,
            
            detailView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: welcomeView.bottomAnchor),
            detailView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor),
            detailView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor),
            detailView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.heightAnchor),
        ])
        
        // add child controllers and add their views as subviews 
        //  of the "container" views
        
        addChild(wvc)
        guard let wv = wvc.view else { fatalError("Tried to load a controller without a view!") }
        wv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        welcomeView.addSubview(wv)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            wv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: welcomeView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            wv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: welcomeView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            wv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: welcomeView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            wv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: welcomeView.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        wvc.didMove(toParent: self)
    
        addChild(dvc)
        guard let dv = dvc.view else { fatalError("Tried to load a controller without a view!") }
        dv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        detailView.addSubview(dv)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            dv.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dv.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dv.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            dv.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: detailView.heightAnchor, constant: 0.0),
        ])
        dvc.didMove(toParent: self)

        // set closure for detail controller
        dvc.closeTapped = { [weak self] in
            guard let self = self else { return }
            self.hideDetail()
        }

    }

    func showDetail(_ feat: MKMapFeatureAnnotation) {
        // if detail view is already showing
        //  let's fade it out, fill it, fade it in
        // else
        //  fill it in and animate it up and into-view
        if detailTop.isActive {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                self.dvc.view.alpha = 0.0
            }, completion: { _ in
                self.dvc.fillDetails(feat)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
                    self.dvc.view.alpha = 1.0
                })
            })
        } else {
            dvc.fillDetails(feat)
            detailTop.isActive = true
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
            })
        }
    }
    func hideDetail() {
        // call the closure to de-select the POI
        detailCloseTapped?()
        // animate detail view down and out-of-view
        detailTop.isActive = false
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.2, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        })
    }
}
```

---

**Welcome Controller class**

```
class WelcomeVC: UIViewController {

    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let subtitleLabel = UILabel()
    let btn = UIButton()
    let anotherLabel = UILabel()
    let imgView = UIImageView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        titleLabel.textColor = .label
        titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24.0, weight: .bold)
        titleLabel.text = "Welcome"
        
        subtitleLabel.textColor = .label
        subtitleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)
        subtitleLabel.text = "This is the Welcome view."
        subtitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        
        btn.backgroundColor = .systemBackground
        btn.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        btn.setTitle("Do Something", for: [])
        btn.setTitleColor(.systemBlue, for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.lightGray, for: .highlighted)
        
        anotherLabel.textColor = .label
        anotherLabel.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 20.0)
        anotherLabel.text = "This is another label.\nI expect you will have additional UI elements here on the \"Welcome\" screen. For now, we just have this label and an Image View."
        anotherLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        
        if let img = UIImage(systemName: "swift") {
            imgView.image = img
        }
        imgView.tintColor = .systemOrange
        imgView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        imgView.backgroundColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.5)
        imgView.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
        imgView.layer.borderWidth = 1
        imgView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor

        [titleLabel, subtitleLabel, btn, anotherLabel, imgView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = .init(top: 12.0, left: 12.0, bottom: 12.0, right: 12.0)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            
            subtitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            subtitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            subtitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
            btn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subtitleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            btn.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            btn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),

            anotherLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: btn.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            anotherLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            anotherLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
            imgView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anotherLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            imgView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            imgView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -32.0),
            imgView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imgView.widthAnchor),

        ])
        
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(gotTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func gotTap(_ sender: Any?) {
        print("Do Something...")
        // for this example, let's change the button background color so we know something happened
        btn.backgroundColor = btn.backgroundColor == .systemBackground ? .systemYellow : .systemBackground
    }

}
```

---

**Detail Controller class**

```
class DetailVC: UIViewController {
    
    // closure to inform that the close button was tapped
    var closeTapped: (()->())?
    
    let titleLabel = UILabel()
    let subtitleLabel = UILabel()
    let closeBtn = UIButton()
    let latLonLabel = UILabel()
    let anotherLabel = UILabel()
    
    var imgViews: [UIImageView] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        titleLabel.textColor = .label
        titleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 24.0, weight: .bold)
        titleLabel.text = "Detail"
        titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        subtitleLabel.textColor = .label
        subtitleLabel.font = .systemFont(ofSize: 20.0, weight: .regular)
        subtitleLabel.text = "This is the Detail view."
        subtitleLabel.numberOfLines = 0
        
        var cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 20.0, weight: .bold, scale: .large)
        if let x = UIImage(systemName: "xmark.circle.fill", withConfiguration: cfg) {
            closeBtn.setImage(x, for: [])
        }

        latLonLabel.textColor = .blue
        latLonLabel.font = .monospacedSystemFont(ofSize: 16.0, weight: .regular)
        latLonLabel.text = "Lat:\nLon:"
        latLonLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        anotherLabel.textColor = .label
        anotherLabel.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)
        anotherLabel.text = "I expect you will have additional UI elements here on the \"Detail\" screen. For now, we'll use a grid of image views with loosely related SF Symbols."
        anotherLabel.numberOfLines = 0

        // let's create a grid of image views so we have some content in the view

        let stackView = UIStackView()
        stackView.axis = .vertical
        stackView.spacing = 20
        
        for _ in stride(from: 0, to: 12, by: 3) {
            let hs = UIStackView()
            hs.spacing = 20
            hs.distribution = .fillEqually
            for _ in 0..<3 {
                let iv = UIImageView()
                iv.contentMode = .center
                iv.tintColor = .red
                let v = UIView()
                iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                v.addSubview(iv)
                v.backgroundColor = .white.withAlphaComponent(0.75)
                v.layer.cornerRadius = 16.0
                v.layer.borderWidth = 1
                v.layer.borderColor = UIColor.darkGray.cgColor
                iv.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
                iv.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
                v.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: v.widthAnchor).isActive = true
                v.addSubview(iv)
                hs.addArrangedSubview(v)
                imgViews.append(iv)
            }
            stackView.addArrangedSubview(hs)
        }
        
        [titleLabel, subtitleLabel, closeBtn, latLonLabel, anotherLabel, stackView].forEach { v in
            v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            view.addSubview(v)
        }
        
        self.additionalSafeAreaInsets = .init(top: 12.0, left: 12.0, bottom: 12.0, right: 12.0)
        let g = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            
            titleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            titleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            titleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -40.0),
            
            subtitleLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: titleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 8.0),
            subtitleLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            subtitleLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
            closeBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.topAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            closeBtn.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: 0.0),
            closeBtn.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: closeBtn.widthAnchor),
            
            latLonLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: subtitleLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            latLonLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 24.0),
            latLonLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
            anotherLabel.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: latLonLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 12.0),
            anotherLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 16.0),
            anotherLabel.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -16.0),
            
            stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: anotherLabel.bottomAnchor, constant: 20.0),
            stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.leadingAnchor, constant: 32.0),
            stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: g.trailingAnchor, constant: -32.0),

        ])

        closeBtn.tintColor = .black
        closeBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(closeBtnTap(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    }
    
    @objc func closeBtnTap(_ sender: Any?) {
        // call the closure
        closeTapped?()
    }
    
    func fillDetails(_ feat: MKMapFeatureAnnotation) {
        // for this example, we'll fill in a few labels
        //  with data from the selected POI
        titleLabel.text = feat.title ?? "No Title"
        latLonLabel.text = "Lat: \(feat.coordinate.latitude)\nLon: \(feat.coordinate.longitude)"

        var idx: Int = 0
        
        if let cat = feat.pointOfInterestCategory {
            subtitleLabel.text = cat.rawValue

            switch cat {
            case .parking:
                idx = 1
                ()
            case .restaurant:
                idx = 2
                ()
            case .cafe:
                idx = 3
                ()
            case .store:
                idx = 4
                ()
            case .hotel:
                idx = 5
                ()
            case .fitnessCenter:
                idx = 6
                ()
            default:
                idx = 0
                ()
            }

        } else {
            subtitleLabel.text = "No Category"
            idx = 0
        }

        let colors: [UIColor] = [
            .systemRed, .systemBlue, .systemGreen, .systemYellow, .systemMint, .systemIndigo, .systemBrown,
        ]
        let symsSet: [String] = ImgData().sysNames[idx]

        let cfg = UIImage.SymbolConfiguration(pointSize: 32.0, weight: .regular, scale: .medium)
        for (i, iv) in imgViews.enumerated() {
            if i < symsSet.count, let img = UIImage(systemName: symsSet[i], withConfiguration: cfg) {
                iv.image = img
            } else {
                iv.image = nil
            }
            iv.tintColor = colors[idx % colors.count]
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Data class** - *so we can show "related" images*

```
class ImgData: NSObject {

    let sysNames: [[String]] = [
        [
            "person",
            "person.fill",
            "person.circle",
            "person.circle.fill",
            "person.fill.turn.right",
            "person.fill.turn.down",
            "person.fill.turn.left",
            "person.fill.checkmark",
            "person.fill.xmark",
            "person.fill.questionmark",
            "figure.stand",
            "figure.wave",
        ],
        [
            "car",
            "car.fill",
            "car.circle",
            "car.circle.fill",
            "bolt.car",
            "bolt.car.fill",
            "car.2",
            "car.2.fill",
            "car.side",
            "car.side.fill",
            "suv.side",
            "suv.side.fill",
        ],
        [
            "house.lodge",
            "house.lodge.fill",
            "fork.knife",
            "fork.knife.circle",
            "fork.knife.circle.fill",
            "takeoutbag.and.cup.and.straw",
            "takeoutbag.and.cup.and.straw.fill",
            "wineglass",
            "wineglass.fill",
            "cup.and.saucer",
            "cup.and.saucer.fill",
        ],
        [
            "house.lodge",
            "house.lodge.fill",
            "cup.and.saucer",
            "cup.and.saucer.fill",
            "mug",
            "mug.fill",
            "birthday.cake",
            "birthday.cake.fill",
        ],
        [
            "bag",
            "bag.fill",
            "cart",
            "cart.fill",
            "creditcard",
            "creditcard.and.123",
            "giftcard",
            "giftcard.fill",
            "banknote",
            "dollarsign",
            "dollarsign.circle",
            "dollarsign.circle.fill",
        ],
        [
            "house.lodge",
            "bed.double",
            "case",
            "case.fill",
            "latch.2.case",
            "latch.2.case.fill",
            "suitcase",
            "suitcase.fill",
            "suitcase.cart",
            "suitcase.cart.fill",
            "suitcase.rolling",
            "suitcase.rolling.fill",
        ],
        [
            "figure.walk",
            "figure.run",
            "figure.bowling",
            "figure.climbing",
            "figure.cooldown",
            "figure.core.training",
            "figure.elliptical",
            "figure.flexibility",
            "figure.strengthtraining.functional",
            "figure.jumprope",
            "figure.mixed.cardio",
            "figure.pilates",
        ],
        
    ]
    
}
```

---

Please note: this is ***Example Code Only!!!***

It should not be considered "production ready" -- it's intended to be a Learning exercise.

Comment: Sorry but I have to disagree with your assessment of the Maps app with regard to transparency. When the second sheet is shown on top of the first one, it has exactly the same transparency as the first sheet. The second sheet acts exactly as the first sheet just as if the first sheet isn't there at all. I suspect that Apple isn't using the same public UISheetPresentationController that we have to use. The Maps app had the "sheet" feature for years before UISheetPresentationController was made available to us.

Comment: @HangarRash - I've tried and tried, but I can't get two screen-caps from the Maps app on a device where the transparency is *exactly* the same when the 2nd view is presented. It's very possible/probable that Maps is using a custom presentation - or not using a sheet mode at all. In any case, the OP doesn't want the Maps' overlaid-views appearance, so the point is kinda moot.